# Im trying to do get data and write in the Text Widget. Bu i have an error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?' how can i fix this?

Tags: flutter

```
setState(() {
          userName = jsonDecode(data)[3]['name'];
          userEmail = jsonDecode(data)[3]['email'];
          userPhone = jsonDecode(data)[3]['mobilePhone'];
          print(data);
      });
```

im gettin this error here: userPhone = jsonDecode(data)[3]['mobilePhone'];

```
 child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: TextWidget(
                            text: "$userEmail",
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: change userPhone as String

Comment: i did it worked ty mate

Comment: try this : (jsonDecode(data)[3]['mobilePhone'])?.toString ?? ""

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it fixed ty so much